# get_shortcode_regex() only matches first shortcode

Tags: shortcode, regex, bug

The Codex has [an example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) of using get_shortcode_regex() to check if a shortcode is being called on a given page:

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/s', $posts[0]->post_content, $matches);
if (is_array($matches) && $matches[2] == 'YOURSHORTCODE') {
    //shortcode is being used
}
```

This only detects the first shortcode in the post content, though. Is that a bug with get_shortcode_regex(), or can the preg_match() parameters be tweaks to make it return all shortcodes present on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (emphasis mine):

> [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because **preg_match() will stop searching after the first match**. [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) on the contrary will continue until it reaches the end of subject.